# How can I be my own Certificate Authority (CA) and generate ssh keys for my client computers

Tags: ssh, certificate, openssh

I have seen a lot of tutorials about how you can be your own Certificate Authority (CA). The tutorials that I have seen are on how to generate ssl keys not ssh keys so I was wondering how do I generate ssh keys like that in Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS? The reason that I want to do it this way is so that I can manage the ssh keys better and to allow me to revoke them if they leave the company so that they cannot access that server anymore.

Comment: A quick Google search turns this up: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-an-ssh-ca-to-validate-hosts-and-clients-with-ubuntu It looks like it may be what you're after.

Comment: @fdmillion I found that tutorial but I want one that is all on one server

Comment: If you want CA server and SSH server be the same, just don't use another server (generate both CA and host keys on the same server). Obviously you need to take care of file names so that you don't overwrite anything if the tutorial uses identical file names on the two servers. If there is some particular part of the tutorial you are not able to apply to your case, please tell us what it is.

Comment: All CA are self-signed. The only difference between a CA you pay to sign a certificate and creating your own CA certificate then using that to sign other certificate is a matter of trust.  You can do what you describe but by default your certificate will no be trusted zero clients.  Of course as others have pointed out you are plan has some serious flaws in it.

Comment: @zagrimsan I do need help with this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-an-ssh-ca-to-validate-hosts-and-clients-with-ubuntu) there is just too much stuff going on. I just need a more simple one. I do not need all of the host names and that kind of stuff because it will be on one server.

Comment: The tutorial is not too complex. You just need to read it **minding that `auth.example.com` and `ssh.example.com` are the same host**, thus you only first generate the `server_ca` key and one host key (say, for the SSH host). Then you configure the SSH host as instructed and go for the `users_ca` key and sign a user key and configure that as instructed in the client machine (which could even be the same as the server, even if that wouldn't make much sense other than for learning purposes). I won't rewrite that complete tutorial for you, you need to try and tell where it fails if it fails.

Comment: SSH uses public/private key pairs for *authentication* (letting someone prove they are who they say they are), not *authorization* (seeing if that person is allowed access to the server). If your goal is to deny former employees access to the server, that's a question of authorization, not authentication. Best practice is to delete or disable their accounts in the traditional way (that is, revoke their *authorization* to log in), rather than trying to block *authentication*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not. SSH does not look at a CRL or something similar to see if a key is still valid. If you want to be able to easily remove access to servers for people who leave your shop, I can think of two options:

1. Don't manage the keys directly, but manage them through something like puppet (this has direct support for adding and removing individual keys to/from an `authorized_keys` file). That way, you have only one place where you need to add or remove ssh keys, and puppet ensures that the changes are activated on all your hosts
2. Disable `PubKeyAuthentication` entirely, switch to something else for authentication which has a central authentication system (e.g., Kerberos does allow passwordless authentication and has a central authentication database, but is somewhat complicated to set up for the uninitiated).

Comment: can't I just delete the public key on the server that goes with the private key on the client side of that user that I want to not allow to access the server anymore?

Comment: Yes, of course; that's also possible. I was assuming you had already tried that but that you have too many machines to make it a manageable option or some such :-)

Answer (score 2):

OpenSSH have since version 5.4 had their own actual certificates. They are more simple in the structure than X509 certificates but have much simliar functionality.

You create a regular ssh key pair and use as the CA. Preferably one host CA and one user CA. Then you can sign public keys with this CA using ssh-keygen. For example

```
ssh-keygen -s /path/to/ca_key -I key_id -z serial \
-n principal1,principal2 -V +53w /path/to/user_key.pub
```

This command will create a file called user_key-cert.pub that is now your certificate. The certificate is valid for 53 weeks and can be used to log in as principal1 and principal2 at any host that trusts the CA that signed the key.

To tell sshd to trust this CA just refer to ca_key.pub in sshd_config like this

```
TrustedUserCAKeys /etc/ssh/ca_key.pub
```

There is also severals ways to revoke ssh certificates (your actual question) and these are referred to in the manuals of openssh. But the basic option in sshd_config is RevokedKeys. You can use both text files or binary KRLs for this.

For more information I have written a couple of guides about SSH CAs
[https://framkant.org/2016/10/setting-up-a-ssh-certificate-authority-ca/](https://framkant.org/2016/10/setting-up-a-ssh-certificate-authority-ca/%20Setting%20up%20a%20ssh%20certificate%20authority)

For more fine grained and scalable access control please have a look at:
https://framkant.org/2017/07/scalable-access-control-using-openssh-certificates/